# Following Up Sent Messages on Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, reply

I use Thunderbird (52.4.0). Occasionally, after sending an email to someone, I want to add more to that email before they reply. To do this, I simply go to my `Sent` emails, click on appropriate email and click `Reply`. This always used to automatically put in the `To` box the address I desire. These days it puts my own email address in there. (On the one hand, this makes sense: I sent the email, so 'reply' shoudl go to the sender.) Let me give an example.

> Suppose my email address is `sam@t.com`and I want to email `john@d.com`. I've sent `John` an email, say, at 12pm. At 1pm, before he has replied, I want to add some more information. I go to `Sent`, and click on the email I sent him. I then click `Reply`. In the `To` box, it says `sam@t.com`; in the past, it would've said `john@d.com`.

As noted above, I'm not saying that this doesn't make sense from a purely abstract point of view. However, it's *incredibly* unhelpful. I often find myself accidentally emailing myself. (When I had Outlook, it did the same; sometimes I wouldn't even notice that I'd email myself, and the person I wanted to contact never knew anything about it.)

My question is this: how can I (or, is there a way that I can) change it so that it's back to how it used to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do this from my gmail account, then I *do not* have this issue; I only have the issue from my uni account. There I have multiple accounts, say `samt@uni.ac.uk` as well as `samt@dept.ac.uk`. On the computer I am using right now, I only had `samt@uni.ac.uk` put in on Thunderbird, whereas on my work (office) computer, I had both. If I sent an email from my laptop using `samt@uni.ac.uk` and then tried to 'reply', as in the question, it does what I want it to (eg, in the above example, it would send the 'reply' to `john@d.com`). *However*, the emails that I've sent from `samt@dept.ac.uk` appear in my `Sent` folder; when I try to follow-up/'reply' to one of these, it tries to email `samt@dept.ac.uk` *from the email address* `samt@uni.ac.uk`.

**I have now fixed it** by adding the second address, `samt@dept.ac.uk`, to the Thunderbird install on my laptop. When I try *any* of the emails now, I get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Reply All`.

Traditionally, *just* replying to a message will address the reply to whomever sent the message. If that was you, well it ends up being address to you.

If you `Reply All` to a message you sent, it will then be addressed to whomever you originally sent the email to.

*Note: This answer is based on functionality within Outlook, and as such is an educated guess.*

Comment: That does put both addresses in. Although, slightly motivated by what you said, I have come up with a solution. \\ I saw that there was no 'reply all' for gmail, but was for my uni account. Upon clicking this, it gave both email addresses -- mine and the recipients. This was just enough to make me realise the solution (see my answer). \\ Although your answer wasn't the solution, it did indirectly help me solve it, so thanks! :)

Comment: @SamT Glad to have helped. I've voted your answer up.